# How do I make a copy of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, variables, reference, copy

I need to make a temporary copy of a variable to make changes to. Here's what I mean:

```
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
var y = x;
y[1] = "2"
//x: ["a", "b", "c"];
//y: ["a", 2, "c"];
```

It's worth pointing out that I'm using an object I defined myself, and not a built in data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method for 'cloning' array of primitive types in JavaScript (based on your requirements) is shown below:

```
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
var y =  x.slice(0);
y[1] = "2";
```

Be aware, that if array contains complex types (objects), then it will keep original references; in other words, it does not perform 'deep' copy on array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = ["a", "b", "c"];
var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
//y = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Then u can manipulate your new object as u want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to clone your object

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)